# changing html5-audio source on image click and playing it

Tags: jquery, html5-audio

This is my code for playing a html5 audio (which doesn't work)

```
$('img.play_media').bind('click',function(){
src=$(this).attr("id");                     $('audio[id=resource_audio]').children('source').attr("src","testuser/resources/"+src);
var audio= document.getElementById('resource_audio');
audio.play();
return false;
});

<audio id="resource_audio" >
<source src="" type="audio/mp3" />
</audio>
```

As you can see, I am trying to get the `src` on img click ,which is set to the image id and in opera I can see the play starting. But, the audio doesn't play. Any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: sorry about the code formatting edited it twice but doesn't seem to work out.by the way this entire jquery code is within another function but i believe the problem is this part only .

Comment: try: jQuery('#resource_audio').attr("src",srclink)[0].play();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please provide the HTML for the img. I've cleaned up your code a bit, but probably won't help with your problem:

```
$('img.play_media').click(function(event){
  $("#resource_audio")
    .attr("src","testuser/resources/"+this.id)
    .get(0).play();
});

<audio id="resource_audio">
  Your browser does not support the <code>audio</code> element.
</audio>
```

- Note: make sure of two things: a) the audio file is actually at the correct location, b) the web server is configured to serve (respond) with the correct MIME-type.

You may also want to look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/audio.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Heading</h1>
    <div id="doc">
        <img class="play_media" id="test.mp3" src="status-on.png" style="width:15px;margin-right:0%;" > 
        <audio id="resource_audio">
          Your browser does not support the <code>audio</code> element.
        </audio>
    </div>
    <script>
    $('img.play_media').click(function(event){
      $("#resource_audio")
        .attr("src",this.id)
        .get(0).play();
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: <img class="play_media" id="song.mp3" src="buttons/Play-32.png"          style="width:15px;margin-right:0%;" >

thanks for cleaning that up.

Comment: yes the audio file is in the correct location and the server is also configured . i have tried playing the audio giving it a static source and it worked . its only this code that is not working

Comment: Is the JavaScript executing after the DOM loaded (does the code come after the img in the HTML code, or is the script wrapped in a jquery dom-ready function)?

Comment: $(function() {
    $.post("admin/timeline.php?refresh=1",[],function(data){
    $('div#resource_list').empty().html(data);      
    $('img.play_media').bind('click',function(){
    src=$(this).attr("id");           $('audio[id=resource_audio]').children('source').attr("src","testuse    r/resources/one more night.mp3");
    var audio= document.getElementById('resource_audio');
    audio.play();
    return false;
    });
    });
}

all of this is in a script tag in side head

Comment: code formatting ...sorry again
so first the resource div is filled with the images and the work is done on image click event
is inside $function(){...}

Comment: Weird. Works great for me. Tested locally on my desktop (index.html, status png, test.mp3). I'm using Chrome... worked like a charm... I'm adding the actual HTML I used.

Comment: i am getting the following errors in chrome console
1.Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) 
2.Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'push' of undefined

Comment: Yup... your file path is wrong. The file is NOT at testuse r/resources/one more night.mp3

Comment: If you send me a URL I can probably figure this out very quick. Its definitely an issue with a file path somewhere in your code.

Comment: i am doing this on local host. wait ill upload the file somewhere

Comment: can you download the file from here it should just take seconds
[link](http://www.4shared.com/file/AfgU41Vf/main.html?)
thank you

Comment: hey thank you so mush the second answer solved it .thank you very much for your time .this on worked !
jQuery('#resource_audio').attr("src","testuser/resources/one more night.mp3")[0].play();

Comment: That's already in the code I gave you. get(0) does the same thing.

Comment: yeah that  is the same thing thank you very much for solving my problem

Comment: I'm curious why you didn't just use the code I originally provided... the other answer provides nothing that my code didn't already have.

Comment: i refreshed the page and saw the other answer tried it and it worked ,came back and saw you already placed the same answer ... please don't be offended you helped me out and i am very thankful .

Answer (score 0):

I could get it to work, unless the source tag already had a sound that it bound to:
http://jsfiddle.net/webwarrior/b2cUz/22/

You need to update the source attribute on Audio, and not source.

The important bit is: `jQuery('#resource_audio').attr("src",srclink)[0].play();`

But this guy seems to get it working: http://css-tricks.com/play-sound-on-hover/

Hope this points you in the right direction.

Comment: var audio= document.getElementById('resource_audio');
  audio[0].play();

do you mean this ..tried didn't worked .i am uploading the .php file